# Clarification for $\beta = {\{\beta_{10},\beta_1}\} $ when fitting logistic regression and the number of classes is k=2

Tags: regression, classification

I was learning from  [Elements of statistics p.120](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf)  under section 4.4.1 **Fitting Logistics Regression Models**

The log likelihood function was given as

$l(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^N {y_i\log p(x_i;\beta) + (1-y_i)log(1-p(x_i;\beta))}$

Here

$$\beta = {\{\beta_{10},\beta_1}\} \qquad (1)$$

and we assume that the vector of inputs $x_i$ includes the constant term 1 to accommodate the intercept.

**Please my question is :**

Assuming we have only two inputs $X$ = $X_1$ + $X_2$ and adding the intercept or constant term ($X_0)$ that contains only 1's, we will have $X$ = $X_1 + X_2 + X_0$. When we find $\beta$ using linear regression, it will be a vector in $R^3$ or the vector will contain three elements i.e $\beta = \{ b_1,b_2,b_3 \}$

How did they get $\beta_{10}$ in $(1)$ and also I want to know if $\beta_{10}$ and $\beta_1$ in $(1)$ are scalars or their vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your first question, assuming that you have two features, $X_1$ and $X_2$, and you choose to include an intercept, the number of parameters that you would expect to estimate is 3, i.e. $\beta = \{\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2\}$. However, if you define a new variable $X = X_{1}+X_{2}$, we could treat this as a single feature and therefore model using $\beta = \{\beta_0, \beta_1\}$

To address your second question regarding $\beta_{10}$ and $\beta_1$. If you look at the next statement on page 120

\begin{equation}
l(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^N {y_i\log p(x_i;\beta) + (1-y_i)log(1-p(x_i;\beta))} \\
 = \sum_{i=1}^N {y_i\beta^Tx_i - log(1+e^{\beta^Tx_i})} 
\end{equation}

We see that $\beta$ is treated as vector which suggest that $\beta_{10}$ and $\beta_{1}$ are the components of $\beta$. Based on this, I would assume that the authors are implying these are scalar values.

Comment: Please meaning you can't use th logistics regression when you have 8 or less features. This is because we can't get $ \beta_{10} $

Comment: You can have more than 8 features - the 10 does not mean Ten. If you have a look on page 119, the authors state that a model with K classes is specified in terms of $K-1$ logit odds - each with their own set of parameters. In your example $K=2$, meaning their is only 1 set. The 1 in $\beta_{10}$ corresponds to this first and only set, while the 0 corresponds to the intercept.

Comment: please can you help me with this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/494532/parameters-of-lda